Finding equation of lines in hyperbolic geometry which satisfy some conditions

Let $p = 1 + i$ and $l = \{z \in \mathbb{H}: |z| = 1 \}$. Find the equations for two hyperbolic lines $l', l'' \subset \mathbb{H}$ satisfying $p \in l' \cap l''$, $l \parallel l'$ and $l \parallel l''$.

I've got some ideas for this question, but have completely no idea if this is correct. I would appreciate if someone can check if my attempt is on the right track and offer some feedbacks as well. Thank you
Attempt: I've drawn a sketch below where $l$ is the hyperbolic line (with radius 1), $l'$ is the hyperbolic line (with radius $\sqrt{2}$), and $l''$ is the red hyperbolic line. I made that the $l'$ and $l''$ intersected at point $p = 1 + i$. So in my understanding, this exercise is just asking to find the equations of the hyperbolic lines for $l'$ and $l''$.
For $l'$ is it simply just $|z - (1+i)| = \sqrt{2}$? But what is the centre for the other red line?


what does $l || l'$  mean?

@WillJagy It means parallel

You will need to be more specific. Do your parallel lines ever intersect?  May they have a common point at infinity?  Added:  starting to get it, your lines   have a center on the real line and a radius. Do parallel lines have the same center?

@WillJagy Apologizes. I did not know parallel lines can intersect so far. Given that, I don't think so.

@WillJagy "Do parallel lines have the same centre"? I would think so using common sense. But it is also very against common sense that the line l' (semi circle with square root 2) and line l'' (Red semicircle )intersect at only one point would have the same centre.

Well. What text or notes are you following? You are not using the words correctly.

@WillJagy Using textbook "The four pillars of geometry" by John Stillwell, but the question is not from there.

See  whether you can find out what your other source  says about the word parallel; in particular, look up ultraparallel,

I guess the responsible thing is to link to my article for, at least, terminology. http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~jagy/papers/Intelligencer_1995.pdf

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_%28geometry%29#Hyperbolic_geometry and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limiting_parallel would be worth reading.
